# What is the equivalent of Puppetforge and Ansible galaxy for Salt?

Tags: saltstack

What is the equivalent of [Puppetforge](https://forge.puppet.com/) and [Ansible galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/) for [Salt](https://saltstack.com/)?

I have read [this website](http://leonardinius.galeoconsulting.com/2014/08/devops-101-on-saltstack-example/), but could not find the equivalent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent of Puppetforge and Ansible's Galaxy for Chef?](http://serverfault.com/questions/809560/what-is-the-equivalent-of-puppetforge-and-ansibles-galaxy-for-chef)

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Chef is different than Salt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [salt formulas](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas) - collected in a github organization. You can read more about how it works [in the docs](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/development/conventions/formulas.html).